# Angular2 rc1, component provider only works if defined at root component

Tags: typescript, angular, angular2-routing

I have an Angular2 component, with a constructor that needs an injection of a `KeyValueService`. This is to 'patch' the new router missing `data` on routes.

**KeyValueService**

```
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';

@Injectable()
export class KeyValueService {
    private KeyValues: Array<KeyValue>;

    constructor() { }

    Set(key, value) {
        ...
    }
    Get(key): any {
        ...
    }
}

export class KeyValue {
    Key;
    Value;

    constructor(key, value) {
        this.Key = key;
        this.Value = value;
    }
}
```

**Root component**

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';
import {Child} from './Child';

@Routes([
    { path: '/Child', component: Child}
])
@Component({
    providers: [
        ROUTER_PROVIDERS
    ],
    directives: [ROUTER_DIRECTIVES],
    selector: 'Root',
    template: 
        '<div>
            <router-outlet></router-outlet>
            <a [routerLink]="['/Child']">Child</a>
        </div>'
})
export class Root {
}
```

**Child**

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';
import {KeyValueService} from './KeyValueService';

@Component({
    providers: [KeyValueService],
    selector: 'Child',
    template: 
        '<div>
            Child!!
        </div>'
})
export class Child {
    constructor(keyValue: KeyValueService) {

    }
}
```

The error I'm getting says no providers for `keyValueService`. If the `KeyValueService` provider is at the root component, it works fine but if I define a provider where it's actually needed, it won't work. Why? it's already defined as a provider for `Child` component.

Comment: Do you actually have `KeyValue` and `KeyValueService` in the same file like shown above?

Comment: Yes, i do have them like that. Does that make a difference when a provider is defined at the `Root` or `Child`?

Comment: A class can't be referred to that comes later within the same file. The order of these files should be changed or moved to separate files. I don't adsume this solves your actual problem, except when you have the other classes in the same file as well.

Comment: Same error after moving them to separate files. EXCEPTION: No provider for KeyValueService!

Comment: I guess @hkm posted the correct solution. Still worth to keep an eye on the order of classes if you have more than one in the same file.

Comment: Not really, i can compile the code and run the application. The exception i posted in previous comment is inside the browser when click a link to navigate to `Child`.

Comment: Then it will probanly require a Plunker to reproduce.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Visual studio wasn't overwriting any generated `.js` files from `tsc` output. No errors were thrown, so never figured why it was happening, but after manually deleting the generated `.js` files it started to work properly.

Answer (score 1):

You should put ',' after `providers: [KeyValueService]`
like this:

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';
import {KeyValueService} from './KeyValueService';

@Component({
    providers: [KeyValueService],
    selector: 'Child',
    template: 
        '<div>
         Child!!
         </div>'
})
export class Child {
    constructor(keyValue: KeyValueService) {

    }
}
```

Comment: That was a typo, fixed it. Thanks and your code won't compile if you're missing ','.